# Custom endpoint for Node Bot built with Bot Composer

Tags: botframework

Currently working with Bot Composer v2.0.0

Attempting to set up custom endpoint and handling for health checks and availability responses.
Also need to access the manifest from another endpoint besides /manifests/{file} due to gateway routing.

I thought this might need to be done through custom adapters but have not been able to find documentation on the process.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a use case similar to this, using the node runtime!

What I did make my own modified version of the [`dialogs-adaptive-runtime-integration-restify`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/blob/main/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs-adaptive-runtime-integration-restify/src/index.ts) with an added route for the health check.

Adding something like this to your runtime should do the trick, it uses the [restify http client](http://restify.com/docs/home/):

```js
 server.post('/api/health', async (req, res) => {
        //do something
    });
```

Then just modify the import statement in your bot's index.js to use the modified runtime.